# Loop through values on another excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to see if a value entered on Sheet1 has a match in the list on Sheet2. When I try to loop through the values on Sheet2 as I am below, I get an "*Application-defined or object-defined error*". Am I referencing Sheet2 incorrectly, or is this another issue?

```
Do While Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
     If UCase(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)) = UCase(sheet1value) Then
          MsgBox "Match Found"
          Exit Do
     End If
     i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Is `i` set to something before the code snippet you provided? If no, then the default value is `0` (zero) and there is no such cell as `Cells (0,1)`

Comment: That was what I did wrong. Thank you!